# Analogues of Perl's modules List::Util, List::MoreUtils functionality in Python

Tags: python, perl

There's a very useful thing in Perl for functional style lists manipulation [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html), [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm). Is there an analogue for Python? I particularly interested in *uniq, reduce, any, all* and *none*.

Mentioned modules offer functions:

- first max maxstr min minstr reduce shuffle sum
- any all none notall true false firstidx first_index lastidx last_index insert_after
  insert_after_string apply indexes after after_incl before before_incl
  firstval first_value lastval last_value each_array each_arrayref
  pairwise natatime mesh zip uniq distinct minmax part

Comment: This are pretty trivial functions wrapped into a few modules.  They can be useful but if you look at the source, you'll see that most functions are one-liners.

Comment: Agree. It's simple. But the idea of those guys is to make code expressive and readable at the same time. 
It's obvious what **uniq(mylist)** does. It isn't obvious what **list(set(mylist))** does.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the functions you mention [are already built-in](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), including `reduce()`, `any()` or `all()`.

I am not familiar with Perl, but from what I understand from the links you provide the equivalent of *uniq* in Python could be [`set()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) (and if you want to keep the original order, `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(mylist))` can be a solution).

Comment: `none()` is presumably trivially `not any()`